# Is there any ways to stop showing component variable from chrome developer tool

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

In my project, I have scenario like before hitting service I need to one Boolean variable. functionality working fine. But in the developer tool i can change the variable value to true by putting the break point before the if condition.

steps:

1. Put the break point before the If condition.
2. Can change the value of Boolean (**userDetailsFlag**) variable to true from **scope** section then release the break point

## component.ts

```js
    this.userDetailsFlag = false
    this.showSpinnerFlag = true;
    if (!this.userDetailsFlag) {
      this.showSpinnerFlag = false;
      this.toastr.error('Please check the user details');
      return false;
    }          
this.serviceRequestService.saveRequestDetails(this.serviceRequest)
.subscribe(data => {
    }, (err) => {
     });
```

Can we prevent showing scope variables from browser developer tool

Comment: if it runs in the browser, it is "visible" in the firefox browser developer tools

Comment: @JaromandaX- How do I stop this bypassing value from Developer tool?

Comment: you can disable F12 and right click for this, if you don't want to inspect and change values

Comment: @yanky_cranky- I can disable these two, but one more option is there to open developer tool from settings.

Comment: @yanky_cranky - you can't stop a user from using their browser - no matter what you've read

Comment: @Chandrashekhar - what does *bypassing value from Developer tool* mean? and why do you want to stop it?

Comment: @JaromandaX- I mean, I can put breakpoint then I can change the boolean value to true from developer tool, then if you release the breakpoint it saving

Answer (score 0):

Using that developer tool, using that breakpoint, customising values in the mid of an execution - All these are for the developer's benefit to understand and debug your code better...

If you do not want your end user to do these hijacks, build the application in prod mode, enable code bundles optimization plugins, code uglify plugins, disable source maps, enableProdMode().... That will give your end users a tough time to even put a breakpoint...

But again, it is for prod mode for end users, for developer mode, you may use those breakpoints and value changes frequently...